# How to specify namespace for sending message to googlecast receiver app

Tags: google-cast

I tried webapp sampler of conneckSDK.
I can launch a googlecast custom receiver app without any problem.
But when it sending message to receiver, the receiver app expected to get message with specific namespace,  for example 'urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.sample.helloworld'

Plz anyone tell me how to specify the name space in sender app with connectSDK?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ConnectSDK uses their own implementation of custom channel for communication with a receiver app and it has a namespace "urn:x-cast:com.connectsdk". You can't set your custom namespace for now.